# Configure STM32F3 PLL timing for ADC read of Power System and FFT

Tags: stm32, adc, pll

I am new to the STM32 series microcontrollers. I have a Nucleo with an STM32F303RE device to prototype a project I wish to explore. I got that model because I plan to slave ADC2 to ADC1 and read the voltage and current simultaneously, using DMA and 1024 samples.

I am planning to read the ADCs using DMA and, when the buffer fills, calculate Power, Volts RMS, Amps RMS, VA, KVAR, and do a FFT on both sets of samples to document the harmonics. Once complete, I may push it out the serial port or whatever, and then repeat the process.  I am doing this to learn the modes and limitations of the STM32.

As I am preparing the configuration, I immediately ran into the issue of not being able to configure a clock source of 61440 Hz through any timers, to operate the DMA sampling of the ADCs.  Looking at the PLL, I was using STM32Cube-MX to adjust values in the clock page but I can't get there.

Any suggestions?

PS: I was using 60 Hz * 1024 samples (you have a power of 2 for FFT).

Comment: From trying Fourier Analysis in Excel, I am planning to gather 1024 samples based on a 60k samples per second.  I will use the first 1000 samples to do the power and RMS calculations and use the 1024 samples to feed the FFT software.  IT seems to work in Excel.  Would still appreciate comments from anyone in the know.  Thanks

Comment: Why 61440Hz precisely ? What clock and which frequency are you using?